# add a sql file in different module to changeset in liquibase

Tags: java, liquibase

my project structure is like below described.

[image]

In myApp (gradle), i have used liquibase for manage schema changes. So what i want is to run sqlFiles (mySqlFile1.sql, mySqlFile2.sql and mySqlFile3.sql) from my "database" module in my changelog  as a changeset.

I know how to run a sql file in the same directory using sqlFile tag. But since these files are in a separate module, i need some help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i was able to do this with the help of gradle task. I tried to find a way to achieve this using liquibase but for me i couldn't find any.

So what i did was i added a gradle task in my `build.gradle` file to copy the sql file from the database forler and paste in inside my resources folder like below.

```
task myCustomTask() {

    copy {
        from "${rootProject.projectDir}/database/migration/mySqlFile1.sql"
        into '/src/main/resources/db/'
    }
        copy {
        from "${rootProject.projectDir}/database/migration/mySqlFile2.sql"
        into '/src/main/resources/db/'
    }
    copy {
        from "${rootProject.projectDir}/database/migration/mySqlFile3.sql"
        into '/src/main/resources/db/'
    }

}

build.dependsOn myCustomTask
```

So my above copy task happens before the application builds. That means by the time liquibase run the changelog, these sql file are available in the resources folder.

So what i did was after adding this gradle copy task, i added a seperate changeset to run the the sql files in the resources folder.

Thats how i was able to resolve my issue.